# document classification with r

Tags: r, classification

I have been trying to follow the [document classification tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1V2McKbkLo) using R and it's really interesting, but when I tried to run the first part of the script I keep getting this error `Error in FUN(c("obama", "romney")[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "corpus"`. I really don't know why that is, but I am hoping someone could help me figure it out.

This is the script:

```
#init
libs <- c("tm", "plyr", "class")
lapply(libs, require, character.only = TRUE)

# set options
options(stringAsFactors = FALSE)

#set parameters
candidates <- c("obama","romney")
pathname <- "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\speeches"

#clean text
  cleanCorpus <- function(corpus){
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopWords("english"))
  return(corpus.tmp)
 }

#Build TDM
 generateTDM <- function(cand, path){
  s.dir <- sprintf("%s/%s", path, cand)
  s.cor <- corpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir, encoding = "ANSI"))
  s.cor.cl <- cleanCorpus(s.cor)
  s.tdm <-TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor.cl)

  s.tdm <- removeSparseTerms(s.tdm, 0.7)
  result <- list(name = cand,  tdm = s.tdm)
}

tdm <- lapply(candidates, generateTDM, path = pathname)
```

Comment: Well, at [8:50](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1V2McKbkLo#t=530) it has `Corpus`, i.e. with an uppercase `C`.

Comment: (`C` and `c` are quite hard to distinguish with the default RStudio fonts.)

Comment: @jbaums Thanks very much, your comment helped rectify the problem.... :)

Answer (score 2):

your path name should be

pathname <- "C:/Users/admin/Documents/speeches"

Note: there is forward slash in pathname

Comment: OP has it right in his code. The slashes in `pathname` are not the issue.